# How to sort and group by column on pandas and then generate geometry Polygon object

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, geometry, polygon

I have a dataframe

df=

| Area | Sequence | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 604582.25 | 320710 |
| A | 1 | 604590.25 | 320704.75 |
| A | 3 | 604579.25 | 320710 |
| B | 2 | 536584.47 | 176977.83 |
| B | 1 | 536570 | 176996.43 |
| C | 1 | 509202.13 | 307995.99 |
| C | 2 | 509205.3 | 307951.24 |

Need to generate into

df1 =

| Area | XY_by_sequence |
| --- | --- |
| A | 604590.25 320704.75 , 604582.25 320710 , 604579.25 320710 |
| B | 536570 176996.43 , 536584.47 176977.83 |
| C | 509202.13 307995.99 , 509205.3 307951.24 |

considering

```
df1['XY_by_sequence'].dtypes == object
```

And convert the object into a geometry object.

df2 =

| Area | Polygon_XY_by_sequence |
| --- | --- |
| A | POLYGON((604590.25 320704.75 , 604582.25 320710 , 604579.25 320710)) |
| B | POLYGON((536570 176996.43 , 536584.47 176977.83)) |
| C | POLYGON((509202.13 307995.99 , 509205.3 307951.24)) |

```
df2['Polygon_XY_by_sequence'].dtypes == geometry
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with type hints and docstrings. You can leverage the pandas methods to quickly process the columns of your dataframes.

Be aware that with only two points you cannot define a `Polygon`, so for these cases a `LineString` is created.

```py
from typing import Union

import pandas as pd
from shapely import Polygon, LineString

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Area": ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"],
        "Sequence": [2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2],
        "X": [604582.25, 604590.25, 604579.25, 536584.47, 536570, 509202.13, 509205.3],
        "Y": [320710, 320704.75, 320710, 176977.83, 176996.43, 307995.99, 307951.24],
    }
)


def main(df_: pd.DataFrame) -> None:
    """
    Entry point.

    Parameters
    ----------
    df_ : pd.DataFrame

    """

    df_ = df_.sort_values(by=["Area", "Sequence"])
    df1 = create_df_xy_column(df_)
    df2 = create_df_polygon_column(df1)


def create_df_xy_column(df_: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """
    Create dataframe having the XY_by_sequence column.

    Parameters
    ----------
    df_ : pd.DataFrame

    Returns
    -------
    pd.DataFrame

    """
    df_["XY"] = df_["X"].astype(str) + " " + df_["Y"].astype(str)
    df1 = df_.groupby("Area")["XY"].apply(", ".join).reset_index()
    df1.columns = ["Area", "XY_by_sequence"]
    return df1


def create_df_polygon_column(df_: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """
    Create dataframe having the Polygon_by_sequence column.

    Parameters
    ----------
    df_ : pd.DataFrame

    Returns
    -------
    pd.DataFrame

    """
    df2 = df_.copy()
    df2["Polygon_XY_by_sequence"] = df2["XY_by_sequence"].apply(
        create_polygon_from_coordinates
    )
    df2["Polygon_XY_by_sequence"] = df2["Polygon_XY_by_sequence"].astype(str)
    df2.drop("XY_by_sequence", axis=1, inplace=True)
    return df2


def create_polygon_from_coordinates(coordinates: str) -> Union[Polygon, LineString]:
    """
    Create Shapely polygon/line string from coordinates.

    Parameters
    ----------
    coordinates : str

    Returns
    -------
    Union[Polygon, LineString]

    """
    coordinates_ = [tuple(map(float, pair.split())) for pair in coordinates.split(",")]
    if len(coordinates_) == 2:
        return LineString(coordinates_)
    else:
        return Polygon(coordinates_)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(df)
```